# Backtesting of outperformance of a benchmark using the Deflated Sharpe Ratio

Tags: finance, portfolio-optimization, statistics, backtesting, statistical-finance

I want to test whether, let's say, strategy A outperforms strategy B.

In Marcos López de Prado's book *Advances in Financial Machine Learning* he presents the following statistics:

1. The Probalistic Sharpe Ratio: the probability that a strategy's observed Sharpe Ratio $\hat{SR}$ exceeds a benchmark Sharpe Ratio $SR^*$ follows a normal distribution when we consider the skew $\hat{\gamma_3}$ and kurtosis $\hat{\gamma_4}$ of the strategy's return:
   $ \hat{PSR}[SR^*] = Z[\frac{(\hat{SR} - SR^*)\sqrt{T-1}}{\sqrt{1-\hat{\gamma_3}\hat{SR} + \frac{\hat{\gamma_4} - 1}{4}\hat{SR}}}] $

However, if we were to run many simulations, just by random chance, at some point we would find some strategy that outperforms our benchmark significantly. So a new statistic is introduced accounting the multiplicity of trials:

2. The Deflated Sharpe Ratio, $\hat{DSR}=\hat{PSR}[SR^\star]$ where $SR^\star=\sqrt{Var(\{\hat{SR_n}\})}((1-\gamma)Z^{-1}[1-\frac{1}{N}]+\gamma Z^{-1}[1-\frac{1}{N}e^{-1}])$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $e$ is Euler's constant. In fact, $SR^\star$ is the maximum expected Sharpe Ratio in the series of Sharpe Ratios (calculated over all backtests). The Deflated Sharpe Ratio tests whether a given strategy's excess returns are significantly higher than zero.

You can refer to [this article](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3167017) for more information.

So far so good. In the book, López de Prado summarises saying that the DSR can be computed on both *absolute as relative returns*.

My question then is fairly simple. I have strategy A and strategy B, and ran $N$ simulations. If I want to test whether strategy A is expected to outperform strategy B, I can simply take A's excess returns over B, and calculate the deflated Sharpe Ratio over that return series?

Thank you all!